# Regex issue for path

Tags: c#, regex

I use the following regex `@"^(.+)/([^/]+)$"` and I need to check
if its path contains alfanumeric like *slash*.
Currently it is working 
but if I put like **aaa/bbb/**  I got error since I have the last path after **bbb**. How can I solve it?

Comment: If you capture with `.` and `[^/]`, respectively, the path will contain quite a bit more than just alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Agreed, the `.*` is a dangerous plan.  something like `(\d*|\w*)+` is really alphanumeric

Comment: How deep can be the path? Is it always 2-level deep? If it is, then `^\w+/\w+/?$` will work for your. If it is 2-or-more-level deep, then `^(\w+/)+\w+/?$` will work for you.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045378/regex-for-path-and-alpha-numeric-character/23045688#23045688). This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

### [Regex](http://regex101.com/r/jP4mM0)

```
^(.*)\/([^\/]+)(\/)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JsgzdoWKcDdb3WV0)

**Description**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group (.*)
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \/ matches the character / literally
2nd Capturing group ([^\/]+)
    [^\/]+ match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \/ matches the character / literally
3rd Capturing group (\/)?
    Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
    \/ matches the character / literally
$ assert position at end of the string
```

---

### C# Code

```
string pattern = "^(.+)\/([^\/]+)(\/)?$";
```

---

### [Alphanumeric Regex](http://regex101.com/r/nP1tP7)

```
^(\w*)\/(\w*)(\/)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dXtBTBf7qJy0f6QS)

Comment: Thanks ,voted up .Sorry but this is part of what I want .I need alphanumeric with slash that's it,can you help please?here you can put @ or $ and its still working...

Comment: @abc123 `\w` already includes digits. And you don't need to escape `/`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov updated and you do need to escape `/` unless you do `@"/";` in C#

Comment: @abc123 Nope, you need to escape \ symbol, not `/`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov according to http://regex101.com/r/sH2iH7 you do...perhaps not with C#

Comment: @abc123 [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/1803777) - and `^\w*/\w*/?$` works fine in C#. `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc123/def456", @"^\w*/\w*/?$"));` or without `@` - `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc123/def456", "^\\w*/\\w*/?$"));` <= you may notice that / is not escaped.