# Regex for path and alpha numeric character

Tags: c#, regex

I need regex to validate path like

```
/addd/dddd

aaaa/bbbb/

a1233/dddd

but not 
@ddd/aaaa
```

or any other symbol,how should I do that?

Comment: writing some code would be a good start.

Comment: _how should I do that?_: By writing code, it might be a regex too.

Comment: I try with the following [0-9a-z\/] without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one(considering only `aaa` can not be a path, if so, add it with pipe):

```
^((?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+/?|/?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)+)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

`(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+/?` is matching paths like `aa/aa/` and `/?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)+` is matching directories like `/aa/aa`. And `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` is checking for additional names when the directory format is `aa/aa`.

[Try this regex at online](http://regex101.com/r/aY3wY3)